# Opening a resource outside an activity in Android

Tags: android, resources, android-activity, drawable

I am trying to open a Resource by passing the result of context.getResources().getString(R.drawable.myimage) to another class that is not an activity.  context.getResources().getString(R.drawable.myimage) returns res/drawable-mdpi/myimage.png  However, when I try and open this file, it throws a FileNotFoundException.

What is the proper way to open a resource outside an activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the code where you try to open the file.

res/drawable-mdpi/myimage.png is a relative path, not an absolute one. I guess you're not opening the correct path by using the relative and not absolute path.

Comment: Yes, here is the code that is in another class that tries to read in the file path.

DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("res/drawable-mdpi/checkin.png");
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));

How do I get the front part of the path to make it absolute?

Comment: I'm not sure if the resources can be read from an app directory other than the assets directory like this. 
One way might be to use a custom data handler and work with the InputStream from context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.myimage)), for the next step then see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830561/how-to-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-datahandler
Not sure if there's another easier way though.