# Convert text file to DataHandler

Tags: java, web-services

I have a text file that I need to send as part of a SOAP request over web service.

Could someone please share the code of getting this text file into a Data Handler (in java)? I know it probably involves streams not sure of the exact code.

Comment: Very similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830561/how-to-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-datahandler, check that

Comment: I actually already saw this, but they were talking about Data sources and custom classes and wrapping, my guess is something like my requirement could be done in 3-4 lines of code.

Answer (score 8):

I think I figured it out..

```
 DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("C:/DBMigrations/Sample_Upload_Tasks.txt");
 DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(fds);
```

Just create a file data source and give it the file and create a handler based on that data source.